# How can I view or log PHP errors with docker's official php-fpm debian images?

Tags: php, docker

I'm hitting a http 500 error, I'd like to log or view the actual PHP error causing this issue.

How can I enable the log? I've looked around for a `php.ini` file but it does not seem to be present?

The specific image I'm using is `php:7.1-fpm-stretch`

Comment: Might be relevant ~ https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/358

Answer (score 0):

You may add your own `.ini` files in this path on the container:

`/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d`

This path is indicated in the response to the `php --ini` command which you can run in a shell inside your container.

You will have to restart the web server (i.e. the container) for your changes to take effect.